# How to toggle break points to the whole class in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I was wondering if there is an option or shortcut for setting the breakpoints to the whole class in Eclipse, is there such a thing? or does it have to be manually set to every block/line?

Comment: put a breakpoint on the class's constructor. :)

Answer (score 2):

Just set your breakpoint at the start of the class, then use F6 to step through each line of code.

You can

Step Over - go over the next line

Step Into - step into the method to see what is happening inside

Step Return - return from a stepped into method

[Eclipse - Step Over](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-stepover.htm)

[image]